# Array_diff - не пойму как работает

Tags: php

Есть два массива которые надо сравнить и оставить разницу между
Есть первый массив:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => dubstep
)
</pre>
```

Есть второй массив

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => dubstep
    [1] =>  black metal
)
</pre>
```

И по идеи разницей был бы black metal, но применяя функцию array_diff, я получаю результат: 
    <pre>Array
    (
    )
    </pre>

Почему так? Как он работает на самом деле?

Comment: Там будут элементы, которые есть в первом массиве, но нет в других. То есть первый аргумент особенный, а остальные уже бесконечные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите [документацию](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) же!

Возвращаются элементы *первого* массива, которых нету во *втором* (и последующих). По существу это разность множеств, не симметрическая разность.

---

Если вам нужна симметрическая разность, делайте так:

```
array_merge(array_diff($a1, $a2), array_diff($a2, $a1));
```

Comment: array_merge(array_diff($a1, $a2), array_diff($a2, $a1));

не сработала если $a1 пришел пустой, еще проверку делал :)
Но эту симметрию я нашел сразу после того как получил первый вариант вашего ответа :)

Comment: Хм, странно, а что именно не сработало? http://ideone.com/WkOAUU