# PHP сравнить два массива по значению

Tags: php, массивы, функции, search

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )
```

Есть какая нибудь функция, которая сравнит два массива по значению элементов?
На примере мне нужно получить в результате массив содержащий элемент с значением [0] => 2

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Array\_diff - не пойму как работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/227923/array-diff-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php). ⁣⁢⁢⁢⁢⁢⁢⁢⁢⁢⁢⁢